# "OR" Condition in branch protection rules in Github

Tags: git, github, branching-and-merging, pull-request

I have a repository with some task specific branches say

1. dev
2. test
3. release
4. master

And project is synced with CI/CD tool.

I have two conditions in my release and master branch

1. Codes can be merged only by PR which is approved at least by one reviewer.
2. Push can be made only by verified source i.e. the CI/CD (this step is required because there are few code changes on successful build and it has to be pushed back by CI/CD tool).

Now when I approve the PR,  Github shows me warning of pending condition (Condition #2)

Is there any way to put "OR" condition for these protections rules, like if it either PR approved or Pushed by CI/CD accept the changes without warning?

Comment: How does your CI capture changes?

Comment: It has triggers based on PR and Tags @evolutionxbox

Comment: Surely a PR can only be raised if the branch has already been pushed?

Comment: PR can be created, but merged only using Admin rights or when pushed from CI @evolutionxbox

Comment: What do you mean by "when pushed from CI"? Are you merging in your CI?

Comment: @evolutionxbox on successful build, CI performs some code changes based on the release type, commits the changes and pushes them back.